# Copy HTML table in rich text on click

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to copy the HTML table from my page as rich text to clipboard and be ready to paste the contents in excel on a single click.

I found a awesome code in Stackoverflow 
[Select a complete table with Javascript (to be copied to clipboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044616/select-a-complete-table-with-javascript-to-be-copied-to-clipboard)

However, the above code will only select the content in the table. Can any one please help to tweak the code to make it to copy table as rich text (table cells contains color and need to be copied) and paste it in excel or any other compatible window.

Comment: How ironic that this is tagged with "copy-paste".

Comment: Hello!  SO is a Q&A site, not a "please write the code for me" site.  You should at least try to make the changes yourself.  When asking good questions it really helps to [do your homework first](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: the demo in the link you've provided does exactly that. Try http://jsfiddle.net/UKHaq/ and paste it in MS Word.

Comment: Sorry for the tag guys. Please don't vote down. I'm a learner.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking someone to tweak the code for you.  You should either A. Do research attempt it yourself and ask for help here if you get stuck or B.  Pay someone to do it on a Freelancer site (such as odesk, guru, freelancer, etc).

Comment: ok guys.. I'm removing the question thread. Sorry. I guess, I asked in work words.

Comment: Yes Travis, I tried a lot and learn't a lot from this site. Hence I posted the question, since I was not able to understand.

Comment: It would help if you stated what you have tried in your question.  How far did you get when you got stuck?

Comment: I can select the entire table in the page. Unable to make it copy. Copied.execCommand(“Copy”); is not working. hence I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a browser is a sand-boxed environment is usually rendered impossible by most browsers (IE a known exception) to copy to the system's clipboard, which is what you want without the aid of flash.  You can use ZeroClipboard to aid in this if you still want to copy.  Otherwise I suggest instructing users to press Ctrl+C to copy.

See this related post: [HTML5 alternative to flash-based ZeroClipboard for safe copying of data to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729570/html5-alternative-to-flash-based-zeroclipboard-for-safe-copying-of-data-to-clipb).