# Programmatic selection of web page content with styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I select with the mouse contents from any web page, copy them to the clipboard and then paste them on an email editor (e.g., Gmail) I get all sort of rich contents copied, like styles, images, etc.

I would like to do the same kind of **rich content** selection, but with javascript.

More specifically, I would like to select with javascript all contents inside a `div`in a web page I own, so that the user just has to press Ctrl+C and then paste the contents on an email editor.

Is there a way to do that? How?

Comment: Is it what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616325/copy-html-table-in-rich-text-on-click

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I wanted, and here's how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Mike238748/LJ74r/3/  thanks!

Comment: @Mike, it's better to answer your own question, if the problem is solved.