# ZeroClipboard not working on mobile version of the site

Tags: javascript, drupal, footer, zeroclipboard

I have implemented ZeroClipboard functionality on our site - http://couponvoodoo.com/rcp/Jabong.com/coupons-offers?field_offer_type_tid=All
I am using Drupal-7

It is working fine on the desktop version but not working on the mobile version of the site.
I have put the following code in the footer :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
copy_coupon_footer();
function copy_coupon_footer(){
var divArray = document.getElementsByClassName("unlock_best_coupon");
for (var i = 0, len = divArray.length; i < len; ++i) {
var offer_type = divArray[i].getAttribute('data-clipboard-text');
// alert('offer_type '+offer_type );
try{
       var id = divArray[i].getAttribute( 'id' );
      var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById(id), {moviePath:'/moviePath' } ); 
      client.on( 'load', function(client) { 
       client.on( 'complete', function(client, args) {try{
      var url = this.getAttribute("href");
       var coupon_code = url.split('&c=')[1].split('&')[0];
       this.innerHTML = coupon_code;
       var classname = this.className+' copied_coupon';
       this.setAttribute("class",classname);
//     window.open(url,'_blank');
     window.location.href = url;
       }catch(e){}
       } );
      } );

     }catch(e){alert(e.message);}
  }
     return false;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: It requires flash plugin on the browser to work.

Comment: @techfoobar Can you tell me how can i check if the flash plugin is installed on mobile or not (PS: I can view youtube videos on the browser)

Comment: This page will tell you the version of plash plugin installed (if it is installed) - http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

Comment: can I check via some javascript code if the plugin is installed or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZeroClipboard requires Adobe Flash in order to perform it's clipboard function and thus it will not work in any browser that does not have Adobe Flash installed.

So, since there are hardly any mobile devices with Adobe Flash (only a few older Android devices), it won't work on mobile devices.

When I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729570/html5-alternative-to-flash-based-zeroclipboard-for-safe-copying-of-data-to-clipb) about an alternative to ZeroClipboard that doesn't require Adobe Flash, no other solutions were offered.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be a bit late, but I have created a pure JavaScript alternative to zeroclipboard that is very easy to use. Here it is: [Github  repository](https://github.com/Triforcey/clip-j). Here is the code:

```
function clip(text) {   
    var copyElement = document.createElement('input');
    copyElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    copyElement.setAttribute('value', text);
    copyElement = document.body.appendChild(copyElement);
    copyElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    copyElement.remove();
}
```