# Select all text from textbox in repeater and copy to clipboard when button clicked

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, c#-3.0

I have a repeater that will bind data's from the database into the text box and every textbox there's a copy button.
What I want is to copy the text from the textbox when the copy button was clicked. 
Btw, I'm using a visual studio 2008 Web Form. I tried using the Clipboard.SetText but didn't work. Im working now with this.

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object,
                              ByVal e      As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
        Handles rpt.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Copy" Then

        Dim btnCopy As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button = e.Item.FindControl("btnCopy")
        Dim txtMsg As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("txtMessage")
        txtMsg.Focus()

        btnCopy.Attributes.Add("onClientClick", "function copyClipboard(){ CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();CopiedTxt.execCommand('Copy'); }")

    End If
End Sub
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button control's client-side click event name should **onclick**.

```
btnCopy.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('button is clicked');");
```

Comment: @Chinx I have no idea how your Javascript is supposed to work. First of all, start with simple Javascript such as `alert('...')`. Then move to complex one. If you get any exception at client side, please post it in your question.

Comment: Hi Win, Im currently working on a work around. The Clipboard.SetText(message), but still dont work. Both on IE and Chrome. I didnt have any error encounter and yet  still the same.

Comment: [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: I copy text to Clipboard using this function. function copyClipboard() {

           CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();

           CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");
        }

Comment: @Chinx Copy to clipboard is not a new thread. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22581382/296861) or Search in SO.