# Jquery/HTML5 Text copy after click element?

Tags: jquery, html, copy, clipboard

Jquery/HTML5 Text copy after click element?
I have text, and inside is span with name "copy" and i want to copy value of .copy span after click.

This is my text:

```
<span class="copy">Donec laoreet interdum</span> lectus, vel pharetra   ligula mollis sit amet. Quisque in nibh id felis scelerisque.
```

this is my jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.copy').click(function(){
        // copy action, ?
    });
});
```

after click i want copy "Donec laoreet interdum" to clipboard.
please help, best regards!

Comment: Please Refer this link : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/jquery-click-button-copy-to-clipboard

Comment: I saw but I did not find my answer or a good solution there :/

Comment: alright try some jquery plugin or Flash

Comment: But, i don't have use flash.. becouse not any user have flash installed in pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript copy to clipboard isn't available because of security which also mean that jQuery isn't able to copy the text to clipboard. You can do it with flash.

http://www.paulund.co.uk/jquery-copy-clipboard

Comment: take a look of github repo, there is also some button to copy repo address. And it is a flash element. U can not doing in pure JS, what's means that libs or plugins can't exist also.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Adobe Flash anymore — browser support is declining. There is a new HTML5-JS-only "[Clipboard API and events](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/)" (Working Draft 21 April 2015 at the time of this writing) which also let's you copy/paste into your OS clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text content like this

```
    $('.copy').text()
```

To copy the fetched text to clipboard you can use a liv such as [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) But this will only work when the user actually clicks on the 'trigger' button. A java script simulated 'click' on the trigger will not work

Comment: Thanks, but i want copy value of span into user clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not recommended by Ecmascript specification to directly copy into user clipboard. One easy way to achieve the similar kind of result by the code below

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

IE has a method for accessing clipboard. Code below works only for IE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function select_all(obj) {
    var text_val=eval(obj);
    text_val.focus();
    text_val.select();
    if (!document.all) return; // IE only
    r = text_val.createTextRange();
    r.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
<input value="http://www.sajithmr.com"
       onclick="select_all(this)" 
       name="url" type="text" />
```

How ever cross browser access to clipboard can be gained using flash. There is an elegant plugin for copping into clipboard: [zeroclipboard.org/](http://zeroclipboard.org/)