# How to copy (CTRL+C) a div with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, copy, copy-paste

There is a div section, occurred below of the form after I filled the blanks and submitted the form and then I need to copy that div section that it is occurred with the information what I wrote on the form. But the copy process will be with a button. As an example the form fields are like below

- Photo: Example's photo
- Name: Example
- Surname: Example_surname

After I submitted this form, the output is like below

Example's photo Example&Example_surname.

When this output is copy by selecting with mouse, everything is okey. I can paste it somewhere easily including the both texts and the photo. But when some users copy these three outputs by selecting with their mouses, some of them says something wrong we couldn't copy at all.

The solution I want to do, a copy button will be clicked by a user and then this output will be copied as well as selecting with the mouse. After the copy with button, a user can paste it somewhere pressing ctrl+v.

So how to do a button for copy the div output easily with JQuery?

Comment: Hope you can find your answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/jquery-click-button-copy-to-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581382/2984474)

They way you want it seems like you will have to use flash. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953655/2984474)