# Quickbase - Is there a way to copy the results from a field to the clipboard?

Tags: api, quickbase

What I'm trying to do is create a button in Quickbase that a user can click on to copy the results of another field in that same record.

For example, I have a formula field that pulls results from several other fields in to one. The user will take these summarized results and copy them to another application. To make the task a little easier I wanted to have a button that would automatically select everything in the summary field and copy them to their clipboard.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to copy to the clipboard using a button click based on this [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/jquery-click-button-copy-to-clipboard).

If the value being copied from the formula field is being used to create a new record you can use a formula URL field.

```
"http://mysubdomain.quickbase.com/db/mydbid?a=nwr&_fid_31=" & URLEncode([My Formula Field])
```

That will take the value of `[My Formula Field]` in the current table and put that value into field 31 of the target `mydbid` table on an add new record page.