# Copy to clipboard within Cute File Browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, browser, copy-paste

I have a problem with the [Cute File Browser](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php/) and this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905277)

On the Stackoverflow Page the copy to clipboard works but when I add the script into the cute file browser to copy the link on click it doesn't work and also the browser ignores the

```
e.preventDefault()
```

code. Can you please help me and say whats wrong?

so this is from the script.js with the added code:

```
// Clicking on breadcrumbs
    breadcrumbs.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var index = breadcrumbs.find('a').index($(this)),
            nextDir = breadcrumbsUrls[index];                            
                    breadcrumbsUrls.length = Number(index);

                    //before it was window.location.hash instead of var cope
        var cope = encodeURIComponent(nextDir);
        var aux = document.createElement("input");
        aux.setAttribute("type", "text");
        aux.setAttribute("id", "temp");
        aux.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;opacity:0;");
        aux.setAttribute("value", cope);
        document.body.appendChild(aux);
        aux.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(aux);
    });
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the value of a hidden text input field?

Comment: @DavidDomain yes, i'm trying to put the url in the hidden input field and than i want to copy the value.... And I tried the script on stackoverflow and it worked there, so somehow it must work in that script too...

Comment: This works for me. You seem to be comparing something with `breadcrumbsUrls`, do a `consol.log` to see if it is giving you what you want. Preventing default action works as well. Take look at the [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7n0qw0jk/). Did not change much of your code, but since i do not know what your HTML looks like and how and where did you include the script, it is hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: It's not working... I put the script in this Fiddle maybe you could have a look? :) https://jsfiddle.net/kevaxq2g/3/ and i uploaded the files here so you can test because the php doesn't work in the fiddle https://static.mximum.com

Comment: Can you at least add one folder on your site? So that there are any breadcrumbs. So i can test. Right now there are no breadcrumbs.

Comment: so I added some stuff :)

Comment: Ok, so this is working on chrome, but not on Firefox. Are testing on Firefox?

Comment: And I think it doesn't copy the link of the files instead it copies the link of the navigation with the arrow on click

Comment: I'm testing it on Microsoft Edge and IE. Edit: But to copy the link of the breadcrump doesn't work in Chrome too.

Comment: For IE there is a workaround. See my answer on this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593297/using-execcommand-javascript-to-copy-hidden-text-to-clipboard/31596687#31596687). Of course it is coping the navigation link, because that is what you are adding to the text input value. Or at least this is what i added to it, since i dont know what is in `breadcrumbsUrls`

Comment: oh.. well but that's not what I want... i want that if i click e.g. on the main page on test.txt it than copies me https://static.mximum.com/files/test.txt to the clipboard... I'm sorry :P

Answer (score -2):

I had a hard time getting that to to work as well. I disected the whole thing and fiddled it.  You are welcome to fork. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrickb767/zc6r2nzL/)

```
breadcrumbsUrls
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more clear what your answer is.