# Copy current URL to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, clipboarddata

Not sure why this has been so difficult for me today, but for some reason I cannot seem to get it to copy the current URL to the clipboard. Overall, I'm looking for a way to do it *without* needing to create some hidden text elements.

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
var shareBtn = document.querySelector(".share-button");

shareBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var cpLink = window.location.href;
  cpLink.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
  event.preventDefault;
});
```

When I try to go about it using the `.select()` I get this error:
`t.select is not a function`
So I'm not 100% sure what the best way to go about this. Again, without using jQuery (or any other JS library) and not using some sort of hidden textfield.

Comment: because it is not an element, you can not select text

Comment: You can't really do it without a dummy element that supports the `select()` method <rant>which is amazing to me in a year when browsers have their own payment integration APIs but lack something as basic as a clipboard API. </rant>

Comment: So what would be the best way to grab the current URL then and get that into the clipboard?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

### You can create a temporary DOM element to hold the URL

Unfortunately there is no standard API for clipboard operations, so we're left with the hacky way of using a HTML `input` element to fit our needs. The idea is to create an input, set its value to the URL of the current document, select its contents and execute `copy`.

We then clean up the mess instead of setting input to hidden and polluting the DOM.

```
var dummy = document.createElement('input'),
    text = window.location.href;

document.body.appendChild(dummy);
dummy.value = text;
dummy.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
document.body.removeChild(dummy);
```

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. It kinda silly that the only option is to create an empty object and then remove it. But if that's the only way...so be it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pain. I've been looking around the Selection API to maybe find a way to simulate the whole thing without the input, but so far no luck.

Comment: wow so you can only use the `execComand` ONLY on text inputs? Wow.

Comment: Just want to mention that this approach at least with Chrome does not work (or at least in my case where I use modal). As a workaround it is possible to pre-create a hidden field, then unhide + change value + copy + hide again: details -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57192718/4992248

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ... it may be a hack, but it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 44):

2021 update: you can use the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) like so:

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.href);
```

Comment: Doesn't work on IOS

Comment: I believe some Async magic is required here. This is a great guide: https://web.dev/async-clipboard/

Comment: @Lafi it DOES work on iOS

Answer (score 6):

this might be one of the simpler ways to do it

```
window.navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);
```

Answer (score 4):

[ppajer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618618/copy-current-url-to-clipboard#49618964) is indeed all that's needed when the browser handles the copying, without any custom handling of clipboard events being involved.

But if you or some library hook into the copy event (say, `window.addEventListener('copy', ...)` and then if that handler relies on using `window.getSelection()`, then [a 19 year old](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686) Firefox issue will bite you. Like [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection):

> It is worth noting that currently `getSelection()` doesn't work on the content of `<textarea>` and `<input>` elements in Firefox, Edge (Legacy) and Internet Explorer.

So, `getSelection()` returns a non-null result after `HTMLInputElement#select`, but without providing the actual selected content. Easily fixed by using a non-input element to temporarily hold the URL:

```js
function copyUrl() {
  if (!window.getSelection) {
    alert('Please copy the URL from the location bar.');
    return;
  }
  const dummy = document.createElement('p');
  dummy.textContent = window.location.href;
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);

  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStartBefore(dummy);
  range.setEndAfter(dummy);

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  // First clear, in case the user already selected some other text
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);

  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

(The above will also work when no custom handler hooks into the copy event.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $temp = $("<input>");
var $url = $('.copy').attr('href');

  $('.clipboard').on('click', function() {
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($url).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
      const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: (toast) => {
          toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
          toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
        }
      })
        
      Toast.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'URL copied! ' 
      })
          
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a pretty similar issue, where i needed to copy a link to a specific header element in my dom.

What i basically did was this:

1. Get Link as Url and as actual Link Element
2. Enable the native clipboard component to copy actual html
3. Copy the link to the header

```js
Element.prototype.getLink = function () {
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = this.getUrl();
  link.innerText = this.innerText; 
  return link;
};

Element.prototype.getUrl = function () {
  return new URL(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '#' + this.id);
};

Clipboard.prototype.writeHTML = function (html, text) {
  let textContent = text || html.innerText;
  let htmlContent = "";
  if (typeof (html) == "string") htmlContent = html;
  else if (html instanceof Element) htmlContent = html.outerHTML;
  else htmlContent = html.toString();

  if (ClipboardItem) //bug in firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem
  {
    let content = [
      new ClipboardItem({
        "text/html": new Blob([htmlContent], { type: "text/html" }), //this can be interpreted by applications like teams or office word
        "text/plain": new Blob([textContent], { type: "text/plain" }) //while this is required for other apps, like plain text editors
      })
    ];
    return this.write(content);
  }
  else {
    return this.writeText(textContent);
  }
};

let header = document.getElementById("some-header");
let button = document.getElementById("copy-button");
let feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeHTML(header.getLink(), header.getUrl())
    .then(function () {
      feedback.innerText = "copied!"; 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      feedback.innerText = `Oops... that shoudln't have happened. ${error}`; 
    });
});
```

```html
<h4 id="some-header">Some Header</h4>
<button id="copy-button" role="button">Copy URL to Header</button>
<div id="feedback">nothing copied yet</div>
```