# HTML Copy to Clipboard and Close Tab

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag, google-sites-2016

I want to create an HTML script that does the following:

1. Copies a URL to the clipboard.
2. On a black background — Shows a green tick and says "Link Copied to Clipboard" for a couple of seconds in white text.
3. Closes the current tab where this script is running.

I want all 3 of these actions to happen automatically when the file is opened in the order above. Ideally, I'd like it to take less than 5 seconds. How can I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Reason: I'm going to add a "Copy Link" button to my website and this is the only way I can do it. I use Google Sites.

Comment: You can try with some add'ons like firefox add's.

Comment: Check this for close a window with js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Comment: have you already started to find a solution?

Comment: @BlockChain Office, but what about people who don't use Firefox?

Comment: @Maik Lowery, not yet.

Comment: maybe this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618618/copy-current-url-to-clipboard  Copy current URL to clipboard?

Comment: And HTML is actually a markup language and not a scripting language. Try the ecmascript family (js|ajax|jquery|etc..) .

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- button to trigger the action -->
    <button id="button">close window</button>
    <h1 id="text">some text</h1>

    <script>
      // get the button
      const button = document.getElementById("button");
      //add event listener to the button
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // get the text
        const text = document.getElementById("text");
        //copy the text to the clipboard
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.innerHTML).then(() => {
          //add time out to close the window
          setTimeout(() => {
            window.close();
          }, 3000);
          // add your toaster  here to show the text copied 
          // hare is some reference https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toast_message.asp
          text.innerHTML = "Copied to clipboard!";
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's very close to what I want. I just need it to do it automatically. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by automatically?

Comment: To automatically copy the text and close the Window. (The confirmation can stay).

Comment: it's doing that exactly

Comment: I don’t want ANY interaction to happen from the user once it’s opened. I want it ALL to be automatic.

Comment: Also, if that isn’t possible, how can I have the “some text” hidden and just have the button?

Comment: you can put any text inside the copy function I added the some text for demonstration you can remove the h1 tag and add any text that you have inside you java script and send it as argument for navigator.clipboard.writeText('add your text ')

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very skilled with this. I'll have to figure it out another day when I have the time. Thank you for your help though.