# Copy text to clipboard from hidden input is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code to copy a text to the clipboard by clicking on a Button. Text is in a Paragraph element, So I move that text to a hidden input field and then copy it to the clipboard. **But this is only working if I move the text to a text field but not a hidden field**. I also tried to `display:none` the input field, but the result is the same. (I can't set it to `visibility:hidden` because the space matters).  How can I solve this?

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var n = $("p").text();
  n = $.trim(n);
  $(".copied").attr("value", n).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
This is the copied text!
</p>
<input type="hidden" class="copied"/>
<button>
COPY
</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="paste copied text here"/>
```

**Here is the editable jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/d9a4x6vc/

Comment: It should work with `opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -1`

Comment: You might also want to add `pointer-events: none`. Or use `position: fixed; top: -100px` or something, to move it completely off screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change the type of the input to text before select then, and bring the type hidden back after like that.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var n = $("#copyMe").text();
  $(".copied").attr("value", n);
  $(".copied").attr("type", "text").select();
  document.execCommand("copy")
  $(".copied").attr("type", "hidden")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="copyMe">
This is the copied text!
</p>
<input type="hidden" class="copied"/>
<button>
COPY
</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="paste copied text here"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem recently. What I did is put that input box position as absolute and moved it off screen. Also notice that even input field width does affect result. I tried to put width and height to 0, and it didn't copy after that also.

Comment: Solved with the solution given by @Chris G mentioned in the question's comment
`opacity: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -1`

Answer (score 1):

As [DavidDomain explains in answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31596687), you need to change your input properties to take the value.

In your case, you can try this:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var n = $("p").text();
  n = $.trim(n);
  $(".copied").css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: "-1000px",
    top: "-1000px"
  }).attr("value", n).attr("type","text").select();
  $(".copied").attr('css','').attr("type","hidden");
  document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
This is the copied text!
</p>
<input type="hidden" class="copied"/>
<button>
COPY
</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="paste copied text here"/>
```