# How to create "copy to clipboard" button in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message" ></p>

<script>
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array("item1","item2","item3");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}
</script>

</html>
```

this is the code and when i generate a random word lets say "item1" shows ,how can i add a button below it that when i click it copies the "item1"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: how do i add the code to the existing code that i have posted

Comment: i need a single button that when i click it automatically copies ,no need to re-type in a box again or anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've added some lines to your code ,try this it works !

```html
<html>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message" ></p><br>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('message')">Copy</button>

<script>
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array("item1","item2","item3");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}

function copyToClipboard(elementId) {


  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

  document.body.removeChild(aux);

}
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the script to be:

```
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray = new Array("item1", "item2", "item3");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.value = random;
    message.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

The message element needs to be a selectable element, i.e. a text input or textarea: `<input id="message">`