# Copy Text From A Div Or From A Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code

when user click on this Button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="someFunction()">Copy</a>
```

The Text Inside This Div To Copy. How Can I Do This??? Sorry For My Bad English

```
<div>Some Text Here...</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: copy to where? to the clipboard, another div, to a variable?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that you are attempting to copy to another HTML element or variable*
First, it may help you to give your div an `id` so that you can easily identify it using javascript:

```
<div id="div1">Some Text Here...</div>
```

If you are trying to use a button instead of a hyperlink, you would then create the button:

```
<button id="button1">Click to copy</button>
```

Then, if you are using jQuery, you could do the following in your function:

```
var myVar;
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
     // If you want to store the data in another HTML element
     $( "#div2" ).html( $( "#div1" ).html() );

     // If you want to store the data in a js var
     myVar = $( "#div1" ).html();
});
```

Here is a [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/vgO5cQ3nNsaZJ34bVQ6J/)

Sidenote, hyperlinks are not the same as buttons. They are clickable, but a button has a completely separate tag in markup.

Answer (score 0):

To copy text from a Div, you'll want either a class or ID to locate that div.  If you're doing this with JavaScript, it would look something like this:

```
[HTML code]
<div id="test">This is the div text</div>
<a href="#" onclick="retrieveDivText()">Click me</a>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
  function retrieveDivText() {
  var divElement = document.getElementById('test');
  var divText = divElement.innerHTML;
  alert(divText);
}
```

Of course, you can return that divText variable (instead of just alerting it), or do whatever you want with it.

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqzvMp?editors=1010