# execCommand('copy') not working in older versions of Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy text in OS clipboard using javacsript/juery.
Before i was doing this operation with the help of flash in javascript.
But now i want to do the same but without using flash.

I used execCommand('copy') and it was working fine. But in older version of Mozilla its not working.
So can any one help me get it solved or is there any other ways to perform this action and yes clipboard.js also does not support older versions.
Hope i will get something to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: `older version of Mozilla` prior to v41, there was a setting that enabled this feature - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: @JaromandaX But how would i change the preferences on user side. I want a better option so that i can change the way of copying text to clipboard.

Comment: I want to perform operation in clipboard. before i was using code with flash but now its not working inFF. So i found solution which is execCommand('copy'). and its working fine in all browser but it do not support in older version of FF (version less than 41). So i want a code that will perform copy to clipboard operation and it will work in all the browsers. It will be great if i will get a solution for it. I dont want to include clipboard.js or other libraries. Thank you

Comment: Seems like there isn't any solution for this. I have searched everything and everyone suggest to use execCommand, but its not working in Firefox 40 and older versions. @JaromandaX can you please simplify or elaborate the process of to enable this feature.!