# Click to copy text javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, toggle

Let me start with that i'm a beginner on javascript and I just about understand a click toggle.
I am making a site like [flatuicolors.com](http://flatuicolors.com) and it that when you click on a div, it will copy the colour. I have wrote each colour in the each div in a P tag and was wondering if you can click to copy the P tag in that div.

```
<div class="main-colour-container col-group-1">
    <div class="colours-featured" id="div2">

        <div class="colour-box" style="background:#F22613;">
            <div class="inside-colour-box">
                <div class="colour-box-text fade">
                    <p>#F22613</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="colour-box" style="background:#F44336;">
            <div class="inside-colour-box">
                <div class="colour-box-text fade">
                    <p>#F44336</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="colour-box" style="background:#C62828;">
            <div class="inside-colour-box">
                <div class="colour-box-text fade">
                    <p>#C62828</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="colour-box" style="background:#DB3D45;">
            <div class="inside-colour-box">
                <div class="colour-box-text fade">
                    <p>#DB3D45</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: It already answered here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22581382/4804765)

Comment: Yes, it may have been asked before but I do not understand still from that thread as I am a beginner at javascript

Comment: Please be specific then with what you don't understand about it, so we know how to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coincidentally I ahd made the exact same PEN once.

[Here](http://codepen.io/shaikmaqsood/full/XmydxJ/) is the link. Hope it helps. :)

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Tick the Answer if it helped.

Comment: That's not a pure JavaScript solution, you used JQuery.