# How do you copy to clipboard after setting a value in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box where I'm setting the value using jQuery's `val()` method. I would like to copy to clipboard after setting the value in this textbox. I'm using `document.execCommand('copy')` but that doesn't seem to work when there is no user action. Is there a different way of solving this?

I set the value in this text after making an AJAX call to the server to fetch a value. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
$('#someVal').val('Some text');
el = $('#someVal');
el.focus();
el.select();
document.execCommand("copy", true);
```

Comment: You might need to use the Flash Alternative as this is sandboxed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Simple way to accomplish use, `clipboard.js` which you can download here. Or else checkout this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without an additional button to copy to clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055620/1201725, (1026 upvotes) The user says: "Automatic copying to clipboard may be dangerous, therefore most browsers (except IE) make it very difficult.". So for the right way, you can use "clipboard.js" like this:

```js
new Clipboard('.btn');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.12/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<input id="foo" value="same data">
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#foo">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

Comment: Can I use it without the button?

Comment: From this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6055620/1201725, (1026 upvotes) The user says: "Automatic copying to clipboard may be dangerous, therefore most browsers (except IE) make it very difficult." so I think that may be impossible, because if you think this was enabled, don't you be angry when a site copies something continuously to your clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Think if you follow the following implementation there should be no issues.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a#copy-dynamic").zclip({
           path:"ZeroClipboard.swf",
           copy:function(){return $("input#dynamic").val();}
        });
    });
```

Also, for further reference visit: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-using-jquery_501.html