# clipboard copy does not work in jquery ajax success method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy a card number into the clipboard so that I can paste it in Notepad. The code which I got from the internet works very well if tried in the developer toolbar of the browser. However if I add that code into my Javascript file and run the project then it does not work. Following is the code:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("CopyToClipboard", "MyAccountSurface")',
  data: {
    controlId: controlId
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(data.CardNumber).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
    alert('copied successfully');
  }
});
```

Comment: You get data.CardNumber when you alert or in console ?

Comment: Yes you need to make sure that **data.CardNumber** return value

Comment: yes.. I do get it......

Comment: You don't need to append and the temporary field for the sake of copying. See my answer below

Comment: Hey with user interaction it is working now. Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:**

User interaction is mandatory to execute `document.execCommand`.
So in your case it is not possible to copy the text from AJAX Response. `It is the security measure that browsers agreed upon.`

Refer [W3C API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#integration-with-rich-text-editing-apis)

> Copy and cut commands triggered through a scripting API will only
>   affect the contents of the real clipboard if the event is dispatched
>   from an event that is trusted and triggered by the user, or if the
>   implementation is configured to allow this.

---

**A workaround with user interaction**

Steps added:

- Place a text box far away from webpage using relative position.
- Add a button in a disabled state. Once data is available re-enable the button.
- On button click you will be able to perform `document.execCommand` since you are directly interacting with browser (`Hence no security issue as mentioned in API`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' + '/posts/1',
    method: 'GET' 
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#toBeCopied').val(data.title);
    $("#copyIt").attr('disabled', null);
  });

  
});
function copyToClipboard(){
    var $temp = $("<input />");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($("#toBeCopied").val()).select();
    var result = false;
    try {
        result = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Copy error: " + err);
    }
    $temp.remove();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="dummy" id="toBeCopied" style="display:none; position: relative; left: -1000px;">
<b>Below button will be enabled once the data is available from AJAX</b>
<button id="copyIt" onclick="copyToClipboard()" disabled>Copy To Clipboard</button>
```

Comment: Hi Gangadhar, If you try this in javascript file, it does not work. It works fine in developer toolbar colsole. 
:(

Comment: Try creating a hidden field before ajax call, then set the value in ajax success function, select the element, then execute copy command

Comment: Still no luck !
:(

Comment: Hey it is working without jQuery, if I add jQuery it stops working.

Comment: I can not remove jquery

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to copy into clipboard on click with Ajax**

Element, which you are going to click has few events: **mousedown** and **click**. And they are triggered in this order. It means that you can send ajax request in first one and work with result in last one and in this case you will not have security problems.

Let me share working example:

```
  $link.on("mousedown", function() {
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    var $temp = $("<input id='copy_container' style='position:fixed;left:-200px;'>");

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        $("body").append($temp);
        $temp.val(data.text);
      }
    })
  })

  $link.on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var $input = $("input#copy_container");
      if ($input.length && $input.val().length > 0) {
        $input.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $input.remove();
      }
    }, 100)
  })
```

You need this timeout with 100ms to wait for ajax response. It can be improved like you want.

Fixed and negative position - I think you know why we need it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what are you copying? `document.execCommand("copy");` requires something to be selected(highlighted) in the first place.

I think in your example, `select` follows .val(). But in order for this to work you need to be selecting an element, not it's value.

```
$temp.val(data.CardNumber);
$temp.select();

copied = document.execCommand("copy");
$temp.remove();

if(copied){
    alert('copied successfully');
}else{
    alert('something went wrong');
}
```

Comment: But, why this code runs successfully outside the ajax call. If i add the hardcode value in cardnumber.

Comment: Hi Serg, value of copied is coming 'false'.

Comment: How do I make it work for a sent text rather than element, as i want to copy it on the fly, i do not want to store it in any element.

Comment: @user2746466 I'm still looking into it but I believe this is a security thing. Copying something for the user into clipboard can already lead to malicious behavior. Doing so completely invisibly is even worse, however I can't say for a fact if it can be done yet.

Comment: @user2746466 I think if you make your new element `display:none` in css, you could at least make it seem to the user like you're not creating and removing an element just for this.

Comment: @user2746466 also, move `$temp.remove();` into the `if` statement. Especially if you end up visually hiding the field with css.

Comment: Hi Serg, I want to copy string not the element. 
Element i am already creating dynamically.

Comment: @user2746466 I know, that's how you do it, by calling select method on the element, not `.val()`. Try that in a fiddle, that part definitely works.

Comment: @user2746466 It's in my example above.

Comment: @user2746466 alrighty man, here's a full example of a working method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
var response;

// recursively using setTimeout to wait for response 
var recCopy = function (){
    if(response){
        copy(response); 
        return;
    }     
    else {
        setTimeout(recCopy,2000); // for e.g. 2ms
    }
}

function copy(value) {
    var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
    tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
    tempInput.value = value;
    document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
    tempInput.select();
    try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy',false,null);
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Oops, unable to copy to clipboard');
        }
    document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
}

$('.copyToClipboard').on('mousedown',function (e){
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.example.com/xyz",
          data: {
             formData :formData
          },
          type : 'post',
          success: function (data) {     
            response = data;  // on success, update the response
          } 
        }) 
});

$('.copyToClipboard').on('click',function (e){
    recCopy();
});
```

ajax call and copying response need to be handled separately (for e.g click and mousedown events have been handled here).
setTimeout can be recursively used to check for response. Once response is received, copy to clipboard can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

As this is not a user interaction, it will not work.

The workarounds which we can implement is getting the data from the ajax call as soon as the mouseenter in the area where user wants to copy the data & place the data in some textarea or input box.

And, on the click event we can copy the data in the clipboard.

//mouseenter event of a button

```
$("#jq-copy-txt").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
       let copyFrom = document.getElementById("jq-cpy-txt-area"); 
        document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
        copyFrom .textContent = data.title;
    });
});
```

// click event fired by user

```
$("#jq-copy-txt").on('click', function() {

   var fn = function() {
      let copyFrom = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
      copyFrom.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
    };
    setTimeout(fn, 1000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Anton said was good but it is all bad practice because You are depending on the server to give You a response at a given time which is bad, You can see in all the big websites that have complicated backend that they just put it in an HTML object so the user could copy it via ctrl+c or via button click, I would've done it a lil bit differently than Antons way

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(e){

    var url = 'Your-link.com';
    var $temp = $("<input id='copy_container' 
        style='position:fixed;left:-200px;'>");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      success: function(res) {
        $("body").append($temp);
        $temp.val(res);
      },
      error: function() {
         //handle error and do something
      }
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $input = $("input#copy_container");
        if ($input.length && $input.val().length > 0) {
            $input.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $input.remove();
        }
    }, 500)
});
```

this way You dont need to reuse event listeners, yet like I said before its far from perfect.
Better put it in a HTML element shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it. You can set value from ajax call return successful to clipboard (first button) or copy text from textarea to clipboard whenever you want it to (second button).

```
<div>
        <div>
            <label>Content</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="fnGenerate()">Retrieve and Copy To Clipboard</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="fnCopy()">Copy To Clipboard</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <textarea cols="50" rows="8" id="Content"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

for the js part

```
function fnGenerate() {
        $.ajax({                
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            ............
            ............
            url: 'someUrl',                  
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                $('#Content').val(data);
                $('#Content').select();
                document.execCommand('copy');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                //Do Something to handle error
                var error = xhr.responseText;
            }
        });
    }

    function fnCopy() {
        $("#Content").select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }
```