# Allowing text selection on <a> tag

Tags: html, css

Here's HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="item">Hello World!</a>
```

And this is CSS:

```
.item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
```

As you can play from this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hy5ugo96/

How can I enable text selection when dragging mouse within a white-box?

---

NOTE: please help me find a solution that works with `<a>` tag, do not use other tag but you can put any tag inside `<a>`.

Comment: I think this is browser specific - eg for chrome, you need to hold the alt key down while you select the text

Comment: Start dragging mouse before white box... or do a white box and INSIDE a `<a>` tag element

Comment: there is a CSS property called `user-select`. However, it doesn't change the default click behaviour. I couldn't make it work as you want yet.

Comment: @Pete Yes, Alt+Drag link content selection now works in Chrome and also always worked in Firefox.

Comment: I don't think it can be done using CSS. you need to use jquery itself. Have you checked [https://clipboardjs.com](https://clipboardjs.com)?

Comment: Or check this answer too.. There can be a treasure in it. [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery#answer-30905277).

Comment: One simple solution would be to not use `href` in the `a`, but to use a click handler instead. Then you can click and you can select the text. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hy5ugo96/9/ (Beware that a select does also count as a click though.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't mark links as whole(thy it on Google for example.) You stretch the link to 100% width and 60px height. in this area you can mark the link. If you start marking out of that area, you can mark the link. Try to do the Stile in a separate object.

Sorry for my bad English. Not native Speaker ;)

Comment: Do you have any reference or specification of why link cannot be masked? at least, for Google Chrome.

Comment: I have no idea. sorry.

Answer (score -2):

you may want to use div just like the following code.

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Hello World!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The select works but now the white box is not a link. So not a solution as per the OP request.

Comment: you can drag mouse from outside the white box then can select and copy the text.

Comment: Yep I get that, but the OP has set his link to be a full-width block so it looks as if he wants a big click-target.