# How do I click hyperlink on a page that copies stuff to clipboard

Tags: html, vb.net, href

Working on a program that keeps track of a users details. I found a site that gives me information but cannot seem to automate clicking the hyperlink that copies info to my clipboard. Here is what I get from inspect element:

```html
<a href="#" class="right hide-on-small-only" id="copy_inventory" data-clipboard-text="RandomLaw's stats:THIS IS WHERE THE TARGET INFO IS DISPLAYED
```

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("right hide-on-small")
        If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("copy_inventory") Then
            Element.InvokeMember("click")
```

RandomLaw being the username, "stats" being constant.
I have been using webBrowser1 but have no need for the window to be seen if there is a better method.  No matter what I do I can only return the hypertext "Copy"

[Here is the website](http://rbx.rocks/user/RandomLaw) - Notice the "Copy" is what I cant click

Comment: Take a look at this, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: Why bother with the clipboard at all? You have the web page, just grab the `data-clipboard-text` attribute directly. (`Element.GetAttribute("data-clipboard-text")`)