# Copy All form data to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am able to copy from textbox but i have a html form which contains field names and values. Below image has the sample form.[image]

When i click on copy to clipboard and paste, it should print the following : -

***** Customer Details *****
Name : JOHN
City : DELHI

As screenshot shows, i want to copy form data to clipboard

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This does not `copy` value, but get the value from the `inputs` and print it into the console.

To copy it. Take a look at [this link](http://Click%20button%20copy%20to%20clipboard%20using%20jQuery) or you can use this plugin [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/)

```js
$('#Ctc').click(function() {
  var name = $('#Name').val()
  var City = $('#City').val()
  
  var ret = "***** Customer Details ***** \n\r Name : "+name+" \n\r City : " + City;
  console.log(ret)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input placeholder="Name" id="Name"></input>
<input placeholder="City" id="City"></input>
<button id="Ctc">Copy to clipboard</button>
```

Comment: @VaTz88 If you read my post, it clearly says that. I have include the links for a few ways to do it

Comment: The issue is the copy to clipboard?

Comment: @MartinWebb well since haven't posted code, its hard to guide him more than i have already, Since SO is not a "Build it all for me" service