# Javascript button with predefined text

Tags: javascript, button, copy

I am working on a project to automate copying text. However, what I would like to do is just have a button that the user can click that will put a specified text to the clipboard.

I am able to do this now by copying text from a text area, however, I am trying to remove the need for a text area and just have a button.

Once pressed it will put text into the clipboard based on the buttons value.

For instance, the below posted snippet has a text area that the button will copy. I want to just have the button, no text area, and once pressed it will copy the name of the button to the clipboard

```html
<textarea id="alu1" rows="1" border="none" style="width:70%; height: 10px">
ssh -l admin:admin x.x.x.x
</textarea>
<button id="alu1copy" style="width: 50px; height: 20px">ssh -l admin:admin x.x.x.x</button>
<script>
var input1  = document.getElementById("alu1");
var button = document.getElementById("alu1copy");
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        input1.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the button to copy the text from the text area to a clipboard, or to copy the text that is on the button? For the latter, you use `button.textContent`. Sorry if I misunderstand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. It is adopted from [this example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands):

```js
var copyBtn = document.getElementById('alu1copy');  

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
  var range = document.createRange();  
  range.selectNode(copyBtn);  
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  try {  
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');  
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';  
    console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);  
  } catch(err) {  
    console.log('Unable to copy', err);  
  }
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
});
```

```html
<button id="alu1copy">I will be copied</button>
```

Here is a **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/xLdLwQ?editors=1010)**.

---

**Update**: HTML with inline JavaScript

```html
<button id="alu1copy">Copy me now</button>

<script>
  var copyBtn = document.getElementById('alu1copy');

  copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(copyBtn);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    try {
      var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
      var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
      console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Unable to copy', err);
    }
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  });
</script>
```

---

If you need something more comprehensive, the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery) works as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, however, I cannot get it to work outside of this snippet

Comment: It works in the CodePen too. Would you prefer inline JavaScript like in your original example? I'll post an update with inline JS inside of the HTML.

Comment: Works like a charm Dan, thank you much. Is there a condensed version of this that doesnt need the console message?

Comment: @JeremyWerner you can remove `var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';` and `console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);` if you want and it will still work. I would recommend logging to the console for the catch statement. If for some reason there is an error, you'll want to know why. The  `console.log` will tell you. Also, if this answer is helpful, could you [mark it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text of a button, just use

```
var elem = document.getElementById("alu1copy");
var txt = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var input1  = document.getElementById("alu1");
var button = document.getElementById("alu1copy");
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        input1.innerHTML = e.target.textContent;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<textarea id="alu1" rows="1" border="none" style="width:70%; height: 10px">
ssh -l admin:admin x.x.x.x
</textarea>
<button id="alu1copy" style="width: 50px; height: 20px">ssh -l admin:admin x.x.x.x</button>
<script>
var input1  = document.getElementById("alu1");
var button = document.getElementById("alu1copy");
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
          button.innerText = input1.value;
        document.execCommand("copy");
    });
</script>
```