# Copy to clipboard using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to copy text to clipboard using jquery. But somewhere I am missing. I have the following codes:

```
<span class="copy-btn" data-type="attribute" data-attr-name="data-clipboard-text" data-model="couponCode" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo $result->coupon_code; ?>">COPY CODE</span>
                  </div>
```

And jquery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.copy-btn').on("click", function(){
        value = $(this).data('clipboard-text'); //Upto this I am getting value
        var $temp = $("<input>");
          $("body").append($temp);
          $temp.val($(value).text()).select();
          document.execCommand("copy");
          $temp.remove();
    })
})
```

So please correct me, how can I copy code to clipboard. I am getting the value of the text, but after that I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581382/244537

Comment: I have tried to get that, but I want it to use in jquery.

Comment: you can go for the javascript solutions otherwise for jquery i think you would need to use something like `zeroclipboard`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have an error on this line:

```
$temp.val($(value).text()).select();
```

Since `value` is already a string, you don't need to try to get it as an input field. Simply use this:

```
$temp.val(value).select();
```

[Here's a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/60yahm9k/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var copyToClipboard = function (text) {
            var $txt = $('<textarea />');    
            $txt.val(text).css({ width: "1px", height: "1px" }).appendTo('body');
            $txt.select();    
            if (document.execCommand('copy')) {
                $txt.remove();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<button address="any text" class="btn btn-login copyToClipboard"><span> copy</span>
```

js file:

```
$('.copyToClipboard').click(function () {
        let str = $(this).attr('address');
        const el = document.createElement('textarea');
        el.value = str;
        el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
        el.style.position = 'absolute';
        el.style.left = '-9999px';
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        el.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(el);
    })
```