# How do I copy clean HTML to clipboard on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, tinymce

I want to copy an image to clipboard when a button is clicked but when I paste it, it always has `style="..."` which I want to remove.

I used the function from [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery).

```
function copy(selector) {
  var $temp = $("<div>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.attr("contenteditable", true)
    .html($(selector).html())
    .select()
    .on("focus", function() { document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null); })
    .focus();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<p id="demo"><img src="/picture/img.jpg" alt="img"></p>
<button onclick="copy('#demo')">Copy Keeping Format</button>
```

When I click the button and paste it in a web text editor such as TinyMCE it displays the image, but when I open the source code it has `style="..."` which I obviously don't need:

```
<img src="/picture/img.jpg" alt="noname" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 0px; vertical-align: middle; color: #454545; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Roboto, Arial, 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; background-color: #f9f9f9;" />
```

How do I make it paste *just* the following?

```
<img src="/picture/img.jpg" alt="noname"/>
```

How i check the data will be copy ?

```
console.log() // what var to print to check the data that will be copy by execcommand
```

**UPDATE**

i try to right click the image and chose copy image and paste it to the text editor and check the source code and get clean img html without `style="..."` so its not the text editor add the `style="..."` right ?

Comment: `$temp.removeAttr("style")`

Comment: @mplungjan I guess the style attribute is added by tinymce editor, no?!

Comment: If it is not on the temp object then yes

Comment: @mplungjan where shuld i put that removeAttr ? i try to put it before contenteditable not work

Comment: Before document.execCommand("copy");

Comment: not work its still have the style=" " on the img tag

Comment: @RickyWijaya This is how tinymce handles pasted html content. I don't know really this plugin but maybe there is an option to paste raw HTML element. Anyway, this has nothing to do with your posted method to copy element. Now i'm guessing there is valuable reason why this plugin add specific style attribute

Comment: i try the other editor and have style too . how i check what the data that will be copy by document.execCommand("copy") , what to console.log? so i can check did the editor or the function wrong

Comment: If you just comment `//$temp.remove();` and then inspect the img element inside the contenteditable element, you can easily see what you get. I just tested it, and ya, the style attribute is added by tinymce editor.

Comment: @A.Wolff do you find the way to copy the clean img html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is indeed on TinyMCE's end, you might want to use paste filters enabled just for images. You'll be able to catch the HTML before it's placed in the editor and do whatever you want with it.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_preprocess