# Why is document.execCommand("copy") no longer working in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

In our application we are using the following logic to copy HTML (text and format) to the clipboard.

```js
function copy(element_id)
{
    var aux = document.createElement("div");
    aux.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
    aux.innerHTML = document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML;
    aux.setAttribute("onfocus", "document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)"); 
    document.body.appendChild(aux);
    aux.focus();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(aux);
    console.log("COPY");
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"><b>Bold text</b> and <u>underlined text</u>.</p>
  
<button onclick="copy('demo')">Copy To Clipboard Keeping Format</button>
```

It was working fine in all major Browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer).

With the latest Internet Explorer version 11.125.16299.0 (Updateversion: 11.0.49 - KB4052978) the HTML is no longer copied to the clipboard.

There is a security setting for this under:

```
Options -> Security -> Edit level ... -> Scripting -> Allow access to clipboard
```

I changed the value from "Ask" to "Activated". This has no effect.

Does anybody know why, what they changed and maybe another solution or workaround? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was not `document.execCommand("copy")`, but `document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)`. While it does visually select the content of the `div` (you can see it, if you don't remove it from the DOM) the selection is not recognized by the copy command.

The following code works:

```js
function copy(element_id)
{
    var aux = document.createElement("div");
    aux.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
    aux.innerHTML = document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(aux);
    window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(aux);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(aux);
    console.log("COPY");
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"><b>Bold text</b> and <u>underlined text</u>.</p>
  
<button onclick="copy('demo')">Copy To Clipboard Keeping Format</button>
```

Comment: I tried this. In my case I have div with table and styles. When I do clipboard copy in IE and paste in outlook my format is gone.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931000/angular-2-ie-document-execcommandcopy-coping-table-td-td-th-not-working