# Unable to copy the text in clip board inside the repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to copy the text in clip board inside the repeater but it's not copying.

Below is what I have tried so far.

```
protected void rptCopy_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "Copy") {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton btnCopy = (LinkButton) rptQuestResponseDtl.Items[0].FindControl("lnkCopy");
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label txtMsg = (Label) rptQuestResponseDtl.Items[0].FindControl("lblComment");
        txtMsg.Focus();

        btnCopy.Attributes.Add("onclick", "function copyClipboard(){ CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();CopiedTxt.execCommand('Copy'); }");
    }
}
```

Comment: Guys please reply ASAP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: this is inside the repeater control

Comment: That does not matter. The copy to clipboard action is front-end, not back-end. Yo are adding the code for copying to a Repeater Button in `rptCopy_ItemCommand`, but the copy itself is not triggered there, nor could it be.

Answer (score 0):

should the `onclick` event be `onclientclick` like `btnCopy.Attributes.Add("onclientclick",...` ? Also you defined the function `copyClipboard` but never called it like `copyClipboard()`... My recommendation is define function in JS file, include it in your ASPX page and then use clientclick event to call the function

Comment: I have used both the clicks. ( onclick and onclientclick) it is not working. It is fetching the value from the text. but it is not copying?? :(