# is possible to copy text after or inside an ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, clipboard

I've tried many ways to copy some text returned from a PHP function called through an ajax call to the clipboard.

I've tried 2 options:

- create the text element inside the function as described here

  ```
  const copyToClipboard = str => {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = str;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
  };
  ```

  from this post: https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f
- and then a second approach, by putting an input text with visibility set to none.

In both cases I'm not able to set the attribute value and then using the function `select()`. As you can see in my code there are even js and jQuery approaches to set value, but no hope!

```js
$("#idStories").change(function() {


  $("#bottone").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var idStory2 = $("#idStory").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/copia",
      data: {
        "_token": "{!! csrf_token() !!}",
        "idStory": idStory2
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        var textC = JSON.stringify(msg.txt);
        $('#xxx').val('marione');
        var el = document.querySelector("#xxx");
        //el.value='aaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
        console.log(el);
        el.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert('testo copiato');

      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare...");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: my question more specific is: "its possible to copy text inside/after an ajax function?"

Comment: what goes wrong when you try? Any errors in the console? Which browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: im on chrome and chromium, ive problem to select() the text, because when i try to do append() inside my ajax call i cant see any child append, and if i try to set a value to an hidden input text i cannot set it!

Comment: I can't see any code to append anything in your example.

Comment: What is wrong with doing `el.value(textC);`  (or whatever data it is which you wish to place into the textarea)? What does "cannot" mean? You get an error?

Comment: thanks @ADyson you spot the problem el.value dont set value... in this case i put just the input/text case

Comment: please show me the HTML for this "xxx" element. Thanks.

Comment: '<input style="visibility: hidden;" type="text"  value="" id="xxx">'

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u7o9tpn0/ - your code should work to add the value to the textbox.

Comment: maybe the problem could be the ajax then? i cannot really understand

Comment: try to use select() inside ajax, thats the problem for me, i try different approach but it fails again and again on this istruction that do not select anything even if i put the text in a textarea on a modal

Comment: are you sure the element actually exists in the page at the time you are trying to access it? That's the only thing I can maybe think of. I can't see how else AJAX could be playing any part.

Comment: ive tried 2 way...create append set value and put hidden field in the dom, set value but for both approach select() wont work... now i write even some code that put the text in a modal, but still no selecting the text...