# copy text dynamically to clipboard after user logins

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have a situation here.the cards are being generated dynamically. the discount coupon is shown only after the user loginIn. once the discount coupon is shown,

```
<div class='col-md-2' style='position: relative;height: 200px;' 
id='showcode'>
<div class="geodir-category-options fl-wrap"style='position: 
absolute;bottom: 0;' >
<div class="listing-rating card-popup-rainingvis">
<a class="trs-btn1 pointer" onmouseover='mover(this.id)' 
onclick="checkSignIn("+i+");" id="+"btn".concat(i.toString()) 
style="margin-top: 0px" >Show discount code</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

onclick on the discount code it should copy text to clipboard.

Comment: Where is your js code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select()` method and `execCommand()` in order to copy text inside an element.

```
var txt = document.querySelector("ELEMENT_T0_BE_COPIED");
//selecting the text inside the element.
txt.select();
//copying content in to the clipboard
document.execCommand("copy");

//store the clipboard value in a variable.
var clipVal = txt.value;
```

You can learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)