# copy text present in button attribute to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons with some text in the button attribute and what I want is when I click to the button it copy to the clipboard

```js
$('.copyboard').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var copyText = $(this).attr('data-text');
  console.log(copyText);
  copyText.text().select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-text="Hello World 1" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
<button data-text="Hello World 2" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
<button data-text="Hello World 3" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
```

When I click it return this :

> Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function

Comment: What's the purpose of `copyText.text().select();`? You already have the data-text content with `var copyText = $(this).attr('data-text');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: @j08691 You need to use `.select()` to copy text into clipboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to copy text into the clipboard, you need to select text on a textarea or an input.
The data attribute is an attribute of the tag HTML, it's not selectable.

You can make this if you put the text into a textarea, select it and remove the tag after copy.

```js
$('.copyboard').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var copyText = $(this).attr('data-text');

  var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.textContent = copyText;
  textarea.style.position = "fixed"; // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in MS Edge.
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy"); 

  document.body.removeChild(textarea);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-text="Hello World 1" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
<button data-text="Hello World 2" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
<button data-text="Hello World 3" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp) example on w3schools shows you you need to use an text field in order to use .select() and then have it copy

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is how you could implement it in your code:

```
$('.copyboard').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var copyText = $(this).attr('data-text');
  var element = document.createElement("input"); 
  element.type = 'text';
  element.value = copyText;
  element.style.position = "fixed"; // Prevent MS edge scrolling.
  document.body.append(element);
  element.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(element);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can only copy a visible and also an input element. Try something like:

```
   $('.copyboard').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var copyText = $(this).attr('data-text');
  var el = $('<input style="position: absolute; bottom: -120%" type="text" value="'+copyText+'"/>').appendTo('body'); 
  el[0].select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  el.remove();
})


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-text="Hello World 1" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
<button data-text="Hello World 2" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
<button data-text="Hello World 3" class="copyboard">Copy</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs `This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes.` See [jquery - select()](https://api.jquery.com/select/)

Similarly, `The HTMLInputElement.select() method selects all the text in a <textarea> element or in an <input> element that includes a text field` [MDN - HTMLInputElement - select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

As a workaround, you can create a temporary, invisible and un-editable input or textarea on each button click, copy the necessary text to the clipboard, and then remove the input again.

See [this article](https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f).