# Copy to clipboard issue javascript from textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have two problems: 
The Java script is not working with IE Edge, not able to copy (IE11/Firefox and Chrome it works). The problem is related to textarea if i change it to `<p>` or `<span>` it works.

The second problem I have is when i past the information into a mail (Browser IE, Firefox, Chrome) I get a screenshot (see image). If i paste it into the notepad i get the correct output

any advice support what can be changed or why it is like that?

```js
         $('.btn').on('click', function(){
         element = $(this).closest('td').prev('td')[0];
         var selection = window.getSelection();        
         var range = document.createRange();
         range.selectNodeContents(element);
         selection.removeAllRanges();
         selection.addRange(range);
        try {
           var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
          if(successful) {
         $('.res').html("Value Copied");
           window.setTimeout(function() {
         $(".res").fadeTo(1500, 2000).slideUp(1500, function(){
        
         });
       }, 100);
          }
           else
           { $('.res').html("Unable to copy!");} 
          } catch (err) {
          $('.res').html(err);
          }
       });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert_message" class="res" style=" color:#FF0000; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold"></div> 
    <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn pull-right btn-success btn-sm" title="Copy Information"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
```

[image]

when i copy into a mail chain why i get a screenshot instead of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to copy just text from textarea? If yes, try something like this (I added Id to textarea to make it simpler):

```
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <textarea id="note"></textarea>
   <button type="button" class="btn pull-right btn-success btn-sm" title="Copy Information"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var note = $("textarea#note").val();
    CopyToClipboard(note);
// ...
// rest of your code with messages
// ...
});

function CopyToClipboard(note) {
    function listener(e) {
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", note);
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", note);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
}
```

[Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/5aqpLobt/1/)

I think it inserting screenshot to email, because you copy page HTML with all tags, not just text inside the textarea.

Comment: Hi JuliaH, thank you so much for your help...just notices that in IE11 and IE edge it doesn't copy...any suggestion ?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581382 this should work in IE11

Comment: @James [Fidler](https://jsfiddle.net/eg9qu0oc/) - I used function from this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581382), it works in all browsers.

Comment: Hi JuliaH thank you for your support, but it is still not working properly. I found a very good solution kindly check: https://jsfiddle.net/j4r9sxwt/  
The only problem is that i'm using a loop, so if i have multiple entries it will copy all text area, instead of the single case (textarea)..  i guess because of the function 'each(function()'.. thank you again for your support.. i guess we are really close on the solution thx.

Comment:  Yeah, you don't need each, just pass value from your textarea: https://jsfiddle.net/rhdL1st8/

Comment: thx JuliaH since i use a loop, while copying the first field it works. but if i want to copy the second field it only copies the information from the first one. At the third field same (first one ect.).. this one works but the only problem is that it copy all fields instead only the wished textarea .. any other advise.. we are really near on the solution ... :)

Comment: @James, so you have multiple textareas and one copy button or separate button for each area? Do you need to copy each are separately or all areas together (like from your Fiddler). I thought you have only one textarea with one button.

Comment: HI JuliaH, Sorry for the misunderstanding.. yes, because i do a loop (take the information from a query) and i have for each textarea a button.  I need to copy each textarea separately. Exactly like from my Fiddler.  Thank you again for your support and help!

Comment: Do you mean code from your post, or this fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/j4r9sxwt ? Because they are different. Anyway, if you mean code from your post and you are adding textareas with related buttons in a loop, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/0a7svx8t/2/ - use class for button and look for related textarea with .prev()

Comment: your  solution works but only if i remove the '<td>' below the example with '<td>'
<td><textarea id="note" name="note"></textarea></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn pull-right btn-success btn-sm copyToClip" title="Copy Information"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>

Comment: @James, I updated fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/53xrvtzb/ Just get value like this: var note = $(this).parent().prev("td").find("textarea").val();