# Is there a way to copy an element what has no unique id or class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that is generated using js. As far as I know, I cant add unique ids to the different cells.

My question is, is it possible to add a function that copies the content of one of the clicked elements that I could add to the cells to copy there content? or is there a way to add unique classes or ids to my cells and the enclosed divs using the js below?

I'm pretty new to js so if it's not too much trouble would you mind explaining any changes made to the code so I can better understand it?

any help is much appreciated!

tried this with no success:

```js
$('.hex-color').on('click', function(){
  element = $(this).next('div');
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(element);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
    try {
       var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
      if(successful) {
        $('.res').html("Coppied");
      }
       else
       { $('.res').html("Unable to copy!");}
   } catch (err) {
      $('.res').html(err);
   }
});

function makeTableRowColors(colors, displayType) {
    var tableRow = "<tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        if (displayType == "colors") {
            tableRow += "<td class=\"hex-color tint-shade-box\"  style=\"background-color:" + "#" + colors[i].toString(16) + "\";><div style=\"background-color:" + "#" + colors[i].toString(16) + "\";>" + colors[i].toString(16).toUpperCase() + "</div></td>";
        }
    }
    tableRow += "</tr>";
    return tableRow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
<td class="hex-color tint-shade-box" style="background-color:#f5f5f5">
<div style="background-color:#f5f5f5">F5F5F5</div>
</td>
<td class="hex-color tint-shade-box" style="background-color:#dddddd">
<div style="background-color:#dddddd">DDDDDD</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: _As far as I know, I cant add unique ids to the different cells_ you can and you should. What will cause you issues is if you add the same id to different items in your page. but your first assumption is wrong

Comment: `next` collects sibling elements, the div you're trying to catch is a child element of the clicked td.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I know this would be possible if I was writing the HTML myself but I'm not sure how I would go about adding them using the JS code I have above. like I said, I'm pretty new to js and don't understand it that well yet.

Comment: @Teemu okay, is there something I could use to collect the child? .childNode?

Comment: You're far better off adding data attributes instead of ids to your markup. `data-id="1"` etc.

Comment: `this.firstElementChild` (no jQuery objects here) would fit to the provided HTML and the JS code using the element.

Comment: @Andy thanks, but how would I have these increase in value for each td or div? e.g. data-id="1", data-id="2", data-id="3" ...

Comment: @Teemu Thanks! ill give that a try.

Comment: i think this is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: @Teemu sorry if this is obvious but do you mean like this? 
element = this.firstElementChild;

Comment: Yes, that gives you the first child element of the clicked element, when the click event is attached to the TD itself. If you have delegated the event, use `event.target` instead of `this`. Notice, that `range.selectNodeContents` doesn't accept a jQuery object as an argument, you need the reference to the native element.

Comment: As long as you know the structure of the document you don't need ids.