# Copy Information From Text Fields with Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

OKAY, BIG EDIT: I think I understand the problem here, so even after changing the code previously provided so that it's selecting properly, when you copy it only copies the bottom text field. I think this is because copy just isn't supposed to work for multiple textareas at once.

My solution for this is to create a new element with JS, have what I want to copy put in that element, select and copy from there?  In my head, this works, but I'm not sure how I would go about actually doing that.

Here's what I tried, but I'm sort of pulling from nothing so it's riddled with errors. I'm very new to JS so I'm sorry how much I don't understand! I used to have this code in the main.js file, but every time I mess something up in it, it throws off the whole thing so I've moved it to its own dohtml-copier.js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Live Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="le-header">live editor by emilie <button class="le-click" onclick="getDOHTML();">copy dohtml</button></div>
    <div class="le-wrap">
        <div class="le-result">
            <iframe id="le-preview" src="">
            <!DOCTYPE html><html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
            </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="le-code">
            <button class="le-tit">HTML</button>
            <div class="le-pannel">
                <textarea id="le-html" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="le-tit">CSS</button>
            <div class="le-pannel">
                <textarea id="le-css" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="le-tit">JavaScript / JQuery</button>
            <div class="le-pannel">
                <textarea id="le-js" onkeyup='saveValue(this);'></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/dohtml-copier.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function getHTML() {
        var html = $('#le-html').val();
        return html;
    }
function getCSS() {
        var html = $('#le-css').val();
        return html;
    }

function getJS() {
        var html = $('#le-js').val();
        return html;
    }
function getDOHTML() {
    var dohtml = document.createElement('dohtml');
    dohtml.append("[dohtml]<center><style>" + getCSS(); + "</style>" + getHTML(); + "<script>" + getJS(); + "<\/script></center>[/dohtml]");
    dohtml.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Created + Copied DOHTML");

};
```

Comment: the select method is to select text inside an element. It doesn't work the way u tried to use it by selecting a string so to say. Just select the text field object and then apply .select()

Comment: ohh. what would I use instead?

Comment: here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select

Comment: if there are multiple text fields though, won't just selecting one mean you only get the information from the one?

Comment: you have 3 variables var html for 3 different things, you need var html , var css  , var js, for example.  One was overwriting the last one... And that's for a start, not sure what else you got here...  You have working examples in answers, learn from them.

Comment: oop! i didn't even notice, yes i'm looking at them and fiddling! thank you!

Comment: @EmilieHepburn posted an answer that I think will help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you would go this way:

```
let textfield_one = document.getElementById('le-html');
textfield_one.select()

let textfield_two = document.getElementById('le-css');
textfield_two.select()

let textfield_three = document.getElementById('le-js');
textfield_three.select()

[..]
```

Otherweise you could create a list of elements and loop it like so:

```
var listOfElementsToLoop = [];
listOfElementsToLoop.push(document.getElementById('le-html'))
listOfElementsToLoop.push(document.getElementById('le-css'))
listOfElementsToLoop.push(document.getElementById('le-js'))

// loop the list of elements

listOfElementsToLoop.forEach(element => 
    element.select()
    etc.
    etc.
);
```

Comment: This does work, thank you but it brought to light a new issue. I've updated my question!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure did I understand what you need, but I made few modifications to this and resolved some errors so you have some working example to work on.

You can see it working here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lj1mgnw/) (SO snippet is blocking iframes). Code copies all elements, gets them into `iframe` and even you get alert of `test js` from iframe, it also apply CSS for test.

You had one huge mistake targeting id's like this `document.getElementById("#le-css");`, you are already specifically targeting `id` with `getElementById` in plain JS so no need for marking it with `#`, this needs to be changed to: `("le-css")`. If you use `jquery` then you need to specify the selector like you did `$(selector)`.

You don't need separate functions to get values of textarea.

You can just append `.value` to it to get codes out of `textarea`.

You also need to escape script tag character in your alert like this: `<\/script>`, otherwise JS thinks its end of the script and produces error you got.

Hope this is on track of what are you trying to achieve.

```js
function getDOHTML() {
 
        var html = document.getElementById("le-html").value;
        var css = document.getElementById("le-css").value;

        var js = document.getElementById("le-js").value;
 
var copyText="[dohtml]<center><style>" + css + "</style><html>" + html + "<\/html><script>" + js + "<\/script></center>[dohtml]";


var doc = document.getElementById('le-preview').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(copyText);
doc.close();

  alert("Created + Copied DOHTML: " + copyText);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Live Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="le-header">live editor by emilie <button class="le-click" onclick="getDOHTML()">copy dohtml</button></div>
    <div class="le-wrap">
        <div class="le-result">
            <iframe id="le-preview" src="">
            <!DOCTYPE html><html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
            </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="le-code">
            <button class="le-tit">HTML</button>
            <div class="le-pannel">
                <textarea id="le-html" rows="4" cols="70"><div id="html">test html</div>
<div id="css">test css</div>
<div id="js">test js</div></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="le-tit">CSS</button>
            <div class="le-pannel">
                <textarea id="le-css" rows="" cols="70">#css {color:red}</textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="le-tit">JavaScript / JQuery</button>
            <div class="le-pannel">
                <textarea id="le-js" rows="6" cols="70">
var iframehtml=document.getElementById("js").innerHTML;
alert(iframehtml);

 </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5b3otynm/44/

```js
$(function() {
  function getCode(tObj) {
    var t = $(tObj);
    return t.val();
  }

  function copyTxt(str) {
    var l = str.length;
    var i = $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      style: "width: 0; height: 0;"
    }).val(str).appendTo("body").focus();
    i.get(0).setSelectionRange(0, l);
    var succeed;
    try {
      succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (e) {
      succeed = false;
    }
    i.remove();
    return succeed;
  }

  function getDOHTML() {
    var css = $("<style>").html(getCode("#le-css"));
    var ht = getCode("#le-html");
    var js = $("<script>", {
      type: "text/javascript"
    }).html(getCode("#le-js"));
    var ct = "[dohtml]<center>" + css.prop("outerHTML") + ht + js.prop("outerHTML") + "</center>[/dohtml]";

    if (copyTxt(ct)) {
      console.log("Created + Copied DOHTML: " + ct);
    } else {
      console.log("Copy Error", ct);
    }
  }

  $(".le-click").click(getDOHTML);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="le-header">live editor by emilie <button class="le-click">copy dohtml</button></div>
<div class="le-wrap">
  <div class="le-result">
    <iframe id="le-preview" src="">
            <!DOCTYPE html><html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
            </html>
            </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="le-code">
    <button class="le-tit">HTML</button>
    <div class="le-pannel">
      <textarea id="le-html"><p>Hello World</p></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="le-tit">CSS</button>
    <div class="le-pannel">
      <textarea id="le-css">p { font-weight: bold; }</textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="le-tit">JavaScript / JQuery</button>
    <div class="le-pannel">
      <textarea id="le-js">console.log("Hello World");</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can get the content of a Textarea element using `.val()`. You can also simply pass the ID to a function if you want to target it as an jQuery Object.

Upon Paste, I get:

```
[dohtml]<center><style>p { font-weight: bold; }</style><p>Hello World</p><script type="text/javascript">console.log("Hello World");</script></center>[/dohtml]
```

Ref: [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)