# Is there any system in javaScript to copy deferent multiple "Input field" with each deferent button or icon?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Description of the project**:
I have a simple project. This project has multiple input fields with a "Copy icon". Every Input has a deferent different copy Icon.

***Problem:*** **When I click the copy icon only the first input filed will select and copy the other copy icon doesn't work**

**I want**: When I click the first copy icon, copy will be the first input field. Again when I Click the second copy icon, copy will be the second input field. This process will be continued.

**Reference Desing**
[Please see the image of this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P25LE.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: JavaScript code: (Do you need HTML and css code)? 
const myInput = document.querySelector("#copyText");
        const myIcon = document.querySelector(".copyIcon");
        myIcon.onclick = function(){
            myInput.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
        };

Comment: Edit it into your code. Also provide your HTML structure. So we can understand how to select the icons and input tags

Comment: Please visit (Can't upload or write html because it's too big so please visit and see the all html css and JavaScript code): https://codepen.io/towkerjoy/pen/ExNpray

Comment: Consider the following potentially helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".copyIcon").click(function() {
    var input = $(this).next();
    if (input.val() != "") {
      input.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
    input.blur();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background: #efefee;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  background: #424242;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arim Madurai;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

section {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

section h2 {
  font-family: Arim Madurai;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #424242;
}

section .box {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.input-group {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input-group label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #666;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arim Madurai;
}

.input-group input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Arim Madurai;
}

.copyIcon {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.copyIcon:hover {
  color: aqua;
}

.copyIcon:focus {
  color: aqua;
}

.reset {
  display: flex;
}

.reset button {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ff1717;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  color: #ff1717;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: .75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reset button:hover {
  background: #ff1717;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ff1717;
}

.input-group textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  resize: none;
  font-family: Arim Madurai;
}


/* Extra Class For Margin */

.one-rem-margin {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.one-rem-space {
  height: 1rem;
}

.half-rem-space {
  height: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Header Section-->
  <header id="title">
    <h1>number and text converter</h1>
  </header>
  <!-- Main Contain Section -->
  <main id="main">
    <!-- Number System Convertion -->
    <section id="number-convertion">
      <h2>Number System Convertion</h2>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Decimal</label>
          <ion-icon name="copy-outline" class="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
          <input type="text" placeholder="eg. 1324">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Binary</label>
          <ion-icon name="copy-outline" class="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
          <input type="text" placeholder="eg. 101101">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Octal</label>
          <ion-icon name="copy-outline" class="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
          <input type="text" placeholder="eg. 174">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Hexadecimal</label>
          <ion-icon name="copy-outline" class="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
          <input type="text" placeholder="eg. 15EEAF">
        </div>
        <div class="reset">
          <button>Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="one-rem-space"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Text System Convertion -->
    <section id="text-convertion">
      <h2>Text System Convertion</h2>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Input Your Text</label>
          <ion-icon name="copy-outline" class="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
          <textarea name="text-field" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="half-rem-space"></div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Input Your Binary Number</label>
          <ion-icon name="copy-outline" class="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
          <textarea name="binnery-field" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="reset">
          <button>Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="one-rem-space"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

This makes use of relative positioning of each Icon and selects the `next` element.

Comment: Many Many thanks for solving this problem. Twisty is supper. Best wishes for the future. Project running perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the `id` attribute is meant to be unique, having the same `id` in the same `document` may not give you the element you want to select.

I selected all the icons from the page, then I picked up selected the input through its parent in case of you have reason to change the DOM.

You should also know that `document.execCommand()` has been deprecated, a more modern approach is using the [`navigator.clipboard API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard)

```
const icons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".copyIcon")];

icons.forEach(icon => icon.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  icon.parentElement.querySelector('input').select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}));

<div class="input-group">
  <label for="">Decimal</label>
  <ion-icon name="copy-outline" class="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg. 1324" id="copyText"> <!-- Don't forget to change the IDs for the inputs -->
</div>
```