# Javascript/HTML Copy to clipboard without flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard

I have a grid that will be containing many columns and data. Now user wants the copy to clipboard button that will allow user to copy data.

How can we achieve Copy to Clipboard functionality **without using flash?**

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Relevant similar post: [HTML5 alternative to flash-based ZeroClipboard for safe copying of data to clipboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729570/html5-alternative-to-flash-based-zeroclipboard-for-safe-copying-of-data-to-clipb)

Comment: I already had a look on all links..Please do let me know if you know anything that we can achieve using Pure Javascript and Jquery.

Comment: @user3463768 https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/flash-free-clipboard-for-the-web/ simple html5 way of coping text to clipboard using `document.execCommand('copy')`

Comment: @SamarPanda: Given that that was in **IE8**, I'm surprised I hadn't gotten soundly downvoted on my (now-deleted) answer saying you couldn't. Thank you for your comment correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new API called [document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) that lets you do copy and cut text to clipboard. It's already [supported on most of the browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=execCommand), expect Safari.

If you want to learn more about it, I recommend reading Google's [Cut and Copy Commands - HTML5 Rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands) and Mozilla's [Flash-Free Clipboard for the Web guides](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/flash-free-clipboard-for-the-web/).

You also might want to check [clipboard.js](https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js) too. It's a super easy library to work with that.