# jQuery copy multi-line list to clipboard

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, copy, clipboard

I've spent some time trying to figure out a solution that would copy a multi-line list in HTML, remove tags and indentions all from a button onclick without using Flash.  In my research I have run across "[jQuery click button copy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/jquery-click-button-copy-to-clipboard)" and I have tested [Alvaro Montoro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/jquery-click-button-copy-to-clipboard/30905277#30905277) but the solution doesn't work on a multi-line list but it works great for paragraph text.  I do not intend to support Clipbaord API because it shows very [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard) across browsers. Researching further I ran across "[HTML5 alternative to flash-based ZeroClipboard for safe copying of data to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729570/html5-alternative-to-flash-based-zeroclipboard-for-safe-copying-of-data-to-clipb)" and Thayne's answer links to a [blog post](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/) but it will copy all the HTML.  I have figured out how to strip the tags and indents:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#therecipe')">Copy List</button>
<div class="listing">
    <ul id="someList">
        <li>1 million</li>
        <li>Monday</li>
        <li>Something</li>
        <li>Foobar</li>
        <li>1tsp blah</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<textarea class="auto"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function(element) {
    var thelist = $('#someList').html();
    thelist = thelist.replace(/\s+<li>/g, '');
    thelist = thelist.replace(/<\/?li>/g, '\r');
    $('.auto').val(thelist);
});
```

How can I copy a multi-line list item with jQuery, remove tags, remove indentions, and copy to a clipboard without using Flash?  Is there a plugin that supports all the latest browsers I am not seeing?

Comment: BTW, to remove tags you can use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: @starikovs thanks, this was my first iteration of testing and I didn't want to post code that was convoluted

Comment: If you use Twitter there's something like "copy tweet link" which shows a modal with selected text and user can ctrl+c it. Why don't you do the same?

Comment: I didn't think of that approach..  I will spend some time reviewing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this solution will work in IE10+, Chrome 43+, Opera 29+, and Firefox 41+. *Not for Safari!*

You're most of the way there, you just need to `select()` the `<textarea>` then use `document.execCommand('copy')` to load it into the clipboard.

```js
var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.auto');

$('button').click(function(element) {
  var thelist = $('#someList').html();
  thelist = thelist.replace(/\s+<li>/g, '');
  thelist = thelist.replace(/<\/?li>/g, '\r');
  $('.auto').val(thelist);
  copyTextarea.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Copy List</button>
<div class="listing">
  <ul id="someList">
    <li>1 million</li>
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Foobar</li>
    <li>1tsp blah</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<textarea class="auto"></textarea>
```

The `<textarea>` is required for this to work, but you can hide it with CSS. It won't be as simple as `display:none` since that disqualifies it from being select-able. You could position it off screen, or follow the detailed advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1832306) to make it invisible.

The extra spacing comes from your HTML indentation, you could get rid of it with `String.prototype.trim()` but ideally I would instead build your list by traversing the DOM instead of using Regex.

Comment: This works great, got a question, got a list with <a> tag need only the text and remove the a tag because is bringing it too.

Thanks

Comment: @RodrigoZuluaga either modify the Regex to strip the markup or use JavaScript to pull out the `innerHTML`